# Relating Schrödinger's Wave Equation and Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, potential, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

A homework question that I don't conceptually understand:

A quantum particle of mass M is trapped inside an infinite, one-dimensional square well of width $L$.  If we were to solve Schrodinger's wave equation for such a particle, we could show that the minimum energy such a particle can have is

$$E_{min} = \frac{h^2}{8ML^2}$$

where $E$ is measured from the bottom of the well and $h$ is Planck's constant.  Estimate the minimum energy of the same particle using the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle and assess the consistency of your estimate with the exact result.

What I don't understand is how can I equate the HUP to this since I don't know what the particle's momentum is in relation to it's uncertainty.  Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle is

$$\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar/2.$$

Since the well is of width $L$, you have a measure for the uncertainty on the position $\Delta x$. Then assume the lowest possible value for $\Delta p$, i.e. the one for which the above inequality becomes an equality. Lastly, use $E = \dfrac{p^2}{2m}$ to find an expression for $E$.

A useful question to look at as well might be [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88167/16660).

Comment: If I know L, doesn't that make the uncertainty of Δx 0, which would mean the uncertainty for Δp is infinite?